# Best Software to purchase

Tags: software-recommendation

I want to create some signs on canvas that have varying words in them for several gifts; different sizes, vertical, horizontal.  Ideally, I want to be able to change the words within the text box and then the words would automatically adjust (if one word is five letters and the replacement word is eight letters) so that I don't have to keep going back and resizing, et cetera.  I don't want to spend a lot of money on the program if possible.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks so much!

Comment: What have you looked into?

Comment: Download [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/en/) - It uses vectors and it's free

Comment: You could just ask on http://reddit.com/r/photoshoprequest if someone is going to do this for you for free

Answer (score 0):

Here is a completely different take on it:

you could simply use an online print-on-demand service, (such as [**zazzle**](https://www.zazzle.com) or [**cafépress**](http://www.cafepress.com/)). The fitting would solve itself, and you might get a lot more flexibility on stuff you can print on and solutions for images, photos etc.

Answer (score 0):

Found this the other day - [Wordle](http://www.wordle.net/)
is an algorithmic toy for generating “word clouds” from text that you provide without the need for propitiatory software. The clouds give greater prominence to words that appear more frequently in the source text. You can tweak your clouds with different fonts, layouts, and color schemes and scroll through more randomly generated outputs until you are happy with the result. The images you create with Wordle are yours and so you can print them out and create gift from them if you wanted.

Comment: Hi Mark, could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the quesion? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!